# Perfectly looped in after effects, however playback pauses/blinks

Tags: after-effects, playback

I've managed to loop a video, and it looks great in after effects, I used this tutorial video

I've then exported as an mp4. Which again, when imported back into after effects loops perfectly.

However when mp4 played back using vlc/windows media/potplayer - it either pauses, or blinks when restarting the loop. It may pause 3 times, then blink, then pause another 4 times, then blink.

Any tips ?  Does reducing file size help or anything ? A different format, I just used the default media encoder settings for mp4.

Comment: What platform are you on? As in, what hardware will you play it back on?

Comment: @tomh Does it matter ? A vareity of different devices ... pc,laptop,ipad,phone

Comment: Seems to me that you’re asking which players will offer seamless playback of looped media. This will differ by application, platform and specs of the hardware, which is why I asked.

Comment: Take a look at this Q/A: https://video.stackexchange.com/q/15376/3908 and also search "seamless" in this stack.